# How do I add a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a GLES game, it has no standard UI elements.  It is based on the code from GLSprite which contains a UIView and an AppDelegate (full source code on github https://github.com/acekiller/iOS-Samples/tree/master/GLSprite/Classes)

The problem I have is I want to add GameCenter functionality and need to open the matchmaking views, but they require I pass a UIViewController to them, of which I have none!

Can I add a UIViewController to my current game (which I would really love to do as I have modified the GLSprite source somewhat and don't want to mess around with getting new code working) and how do I add it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html?

Comment: I tried adding UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 self.window.rootViewController = vc;
 [window makeKeyAndVisible]; at the end of applicationDidFinishLaunching but then I don't receive touches anymore, I'm guessing the new controller is eating them?

Comment: Did you set your view controller's view property to an instance of EAGLView?

Comment: I did not, I added that and it now is working with touches :)  But the screen rotation is messed up, I have added another question here since it requires more explanation.  Thank you very much for your help :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672227/adding-uiviewcontroller-messes-up-screen-orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this to the end of applicationDidFinishLaunching

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view = glView;
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```