# Adding UIViewController messes up screen orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, uiviewcontroller, screen-orientation

I started with a `GLSprite` sample app ([source code](https://github.com/acekiller/iOS-Samples/tree/master/GLSprite/Classes)), then added a `UIViewController` by adding

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view = glView;
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

to the end of `GLSpriteAppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching.`  The controller seems to be working as now I can pop up gamecenter windows, but it has messed up my screen `orientation`.  The app is fine in `portrait`, but in all other `rotations` it incorrectly has white bars on the side, like one of the views is rotated 90 degrees.

I was doing `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];` in `EAGLView::initWithCoder`, I then tried moving it to the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching` but it had the same behavior.

Can anyone help?  What can I do to fix or debug this?  Thank you!

Comment: I'm thinking since I had no rootViewController before and now I do, I need to create a custom viewcontroller and implement shouldAutorotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the new UIViewController was rotating, when my game expects an always portrait screen.  To fix I created a custom viewcontroller and implemented

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return 0;
}
```